# Is it true that a functor from a locally small category with a left adjoint is representable?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-operators

Consider the functor $F: B \rightarrow Set$ where $B$ is a locally small category.

Is it true that if $F$ has a left adjoint then it is representable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I looked for a counterexample among some common categories but couldnt find one, so I'm suspecting it's true. I understand we'd like to construct the natural isomorphism between $F$ and $Hom(A,-)$ using the adjoint somehow, but I honestly have no ideas where to start. Hints would be as appreciated as an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. See for instance "Algebraic Theories: A Categorical Introduction to General Algebra" by J. Adámek, J. Rosický, E. M. Vitale, page 7 (chapter 0, section 0.10 about representable functors).

*Proof*: Let $L \dashv F$ and $1 = \{*\}$. Then,
\begin{align}
Fb \cong \mathbf{Set}(1,Fb) \cong B(L1,b)
\end{align}
naturally in $b \in B$, hence $F \cong H^{L1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Does this remark have a number? All I see on page 7 is a lemma about Yoneda embedding preserving finite coproducts, am I looking at the wrong page?

Comment: Could you explain the notation in the last symbol, $H^{F1}$? I see that you showed $F \cong B(L1, -)$ which is what we wanted, but I'm not sure how $H^{F1}$ expresses that. Did you mean $H^{L1}$ or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe we have different editions. I refer to chapter 0 (Preliminaries), section 0.10 (Representable functors).

Comment: Yeah I think this might have changed across editions, the one under this link http://www.iti.cs.tu-bs.de/~adamek/algebraic_theories.pdf seems to be missing what you posted.

Comment: Of course, thank you! It is $H^{L1}$. I fixed the typo.